# same implemention on java and python, two very different running times

Tags: java, python, time

My friend and I made a program to do the same thing, his was in java and mine in python. The question we had to solve was "What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?" We both got the right answers, and as far as I can tell implemented pretty similarly, but his one finished in a about three seconds while mine took over a minute. Can anyone possibly see why this happened?  Just to be clear, I know that both ways aren't the best, but they both worked and what I'm interested in is seeing why there was such a significant time difference. Thanks!

Java:

```
for (int i = 1; i > 0; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 21; j++) { 
        if (i % j != 0) {                  
            break;
        }
        if (j == 20) {
            System.out.println("ANSWER: " + i);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

python:

```
e=1
while e > 0 :
    num =1
    while num < 21:

        if e % num != 0:
            break
        num += 1



    if num == 21:
        print e
        break
    e += 1
```

Comment: try it on C instead of java you might get faster result.. point of the comment... different languages different speed :P

Comment: @Darkyen those days are way behind us :-)

Comment: @BenTurner nah... sometimes we still get just a lil bit more perf.. using c / C++ ...

Comment: Took only about 5 seconds for me (Java)

Comment: though interesting... how well he formatted python :->

Answer (score 6):

While your implementation in python looks similar, the indentation is very important. In the Java version, this block:

```
if(j == 20){
    System.out.println("ANSWER: " + i);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

is inside the second for loop. In the python version, the block:

```
if num == 21:
    print e
    break
```

is outside the second while loop.

Comment: Which would tend to make the Python faster than the Java.  (It's true, however, that the Java code is a bit strange;  I would have written the inner loop in more or less the same way he did in Python.)

Comment: Yeah, I do not think is the best possible implementation either way, and the performance will never be exactly the same with two languages, but the difference in this case must be because the algorithm is different.

Comment: Except that the basic algorithm is the same in both cases.  He's only moved the second `if` into the inner loop i Java because he has declared `j` so that it won't be visible in the outer loop.  The extra test would make Java slower, not faster.  The difference isn't due to the languages per se, of course; but to the (almost universal) implementation of the languages.

Answer (score 3):

Most Java implementations will compile the byte code to machine
code; even if it doesn't, Java's byte code corresponds
relatively closely to basic machine operations.  In addition, of
course, an `int` in Java is a basic machine type; in Python,
it's a class type, with full support for overflow detection and
conversion to long int if necessary, with a function call for
the addition, and the function looked up in a map on the type.

EDIT:

To make it clearer what I am saying, consider a statement of the
form `i += 1` in Python, `++ i` in Java.  In the absence of
a JIT compiler, the byte code in Java will resume in something
along the lines of:

```
push i
push 1
add
pop i
```

The byte code might be executed by a large switch: each of the
byte code instructions above will take at the most two or three
machine instructions.  The address of `i` will be compiled into
the byte code, and the variable itself will be the equivalent of
an `int32_t` in C.

In Python, the equivalent pseudo-code would be something along the
lines of:

```
look up i in the module's dictionary.
look up __add__ in the resulting object's dictionary.
call the i.__iadd__( int(1) )
```

And `i.__iadd__` will not only add the values, but check for
overflow and convert the type to long if necessary.

In short, in the worst case (because with a JIT compiler, the
Java code for this would result in a single machine instruction
on an Intel processor), we're talking about 10-20 machine
instructions for Java.  Where as the number of machine
instructions for Python could easily measure in the thousands.

Comment: I believe that compilability of the language is not the most important cause of the speed difference, but the difference in algorithm is.

Comment: @JanDvorak Except that he's basically using the same algorithm in both cases.